# How to support a heavy wooden lid in a copper sink

Tags: kitchen-sink, welding

We have a wood kitchen surface and a pretty large copper sink. The hole is prepared for the sink, which we originally wanted undermounted with a positive reveal.

The idea was that the wooden cutout would be used as a lid to fill the hole when the sink wasn't in use and a cutting or work surface when the sink was in use.

However the copper sink looks much better overmounted. I would still like to be able to place the lid in the sink though, even with the copper rim around, and ideally have it flush with the remainder of the kitchen surface.

My question is, what can I do to support the lid in the sink? Can I tack weld something onto the inner sides of the sink, and if so what can I do to achieve that.If I hammer some kind of studs through into the wood surface, what can I do to seal the object hammered through?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create some hooks out of straps of metal to hold the lid in place.  If you made these out of copper, they would match the sink.  You could probably make them out of plumbing pipe, which you sand, hammer flat, and lacquer.  Alternatively, stainless steel to contrast with the sink.

You'll need to think about a handle so that you can get the lid in and out.

Section view:

```
 ----+              +----
\\\##|\\\\\\\\\\\\\\|##\\\
   ##+---         --+##
   ##                ##
   ####################

# - Copper sink
\ - Wooden worktop and lid
- - Metal hooks
```

Plan view

```
\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\
\\\\\\\##############\\\\\
\\\\\\\#\\\\\\\\\\\\#\\\\\
\\\\----+\\\\\\\\\\+----\\
\\\\\\\#\\\\\\\\\\\\#\\\\\
\\\\\\\#\\\\\\\\\\\\#\\\\\
\\\\----+\\\\\\\\\\+----\\
\\\\\\\#\\\\\\\\\\\\#\\\\\
\\\\\\\##############\\\\\
```

Comment: Why did I not think of that!? That's an excellent suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Idea 1: Take two strips of wood.  Attache them to either end of the cutout so they overlap the edges of the sink.  You can shape these so they are also the handles to lift it in and out.  It can also double as a serving tray for canapes.

Idea 2: Put legs on it that support the cutout on the bottom of the sink.  Can also be used for breakfast in bed.

Some downsides:  A sink cover like this makes it difficult to run water before filling something.  E.g.  I often want to fill the tea kettle with hot water to shorten the time.  Or I want to run the cold water to get the colder water in the pressure tank.  There may be merit in a partial cover.

I see a potential problem lurking in the wings:

Scenario:

Kid comes to get a drink.  Lid is in place.  Kid fails to get the water shut off completely.  4 hours later you have a large puddle on the floor.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot upvote this answer as I am a new user. Both great suggestions. We are actually leaning towards the 2nd idea because we also like to sit on the floor and the cut out with stilts could serve as a small table from time to time, as well breakfast in bed. I think for the leakage scenario I could route some channels around the top edge and drill some holes. Perhaps the handles could be removable and inserted into these holes, meaning that the channels would catch spilt coffee for breakfast in bed, blocked preventing leakage onto bedclothes.